# WinSCP to Pi from external network (DDNS/Port forward SSH)

Tags: pi-3, ssh, putty

I have setup home network to use DDNS such that I can login to router from outside network using the custom domain.

I have assigned static (local) IP address to raspberry Pi.

I have port forwarded to this local IP on port 22 for SSH.

I can use PuTTY to login via the DDNS host name to access Pi remotely.

Unfortunately the same settings do not work with WinSCP to do file transfer (SFTP).

---

**PuTTY** settings *(working)* look like:

**Host Name (or IP address)** - ddnsHostName:ddnsPort

**Port** - 22

**Connection Type** - SSH

---

**WinSCP** settings *(not working)* look like:

**File protocol** - SFTP

**Host Name (or IP address)** - ddnsHostName:ddnsPort

**Port number** - 22

**User name** - pi

---

**WinSCP** error is: Host "ddnsHostName:ddnsPort" does not exist

Comment: it all looks ok, except I don't get why the host name includes the `:ddnsPort` - perhaps just use `ddnsHostName` since `port` is separately configured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Host Name (or IP address) - ddnsHostName:ddnsPort
```

you should **NOT** put the port here, that's configured in

```
Port number - 22
```

So, change the Host Name config to

```
Host Name (or IP address) - ddnsHostName
```